# how to type in hindi in visual basic 2005 textbox in desktop application

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio-2005

what i need is to create an application that have textbox like full_name and father_name.

now i want to type hindi in textox field like ms-word.

I dont know what to do.

I am biggner in visual-basic

i am using this code to insert values in sql

```
    Try
        connection.Open()
        cmd1 = New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO admin_users(id, username, password, is_active) VALUES('" + id + "', '" + username.Text + "', '" + password.Text + "', '" + is_active_set + "' )", connection)
        ra = cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MsgBox("Category Added!!")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Category Failed to add!!")
    End Try
```

Please give me some idea how i can do this.

Comment: Use SqlParameters. It will handle most of convertion job, but must of all, it will help you to **prevent [Sql Injection Attack](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9378/SQL-Injection-Attacks-and-Some-Tips-on-How-to-Prev)**

Answer (score 1):

You can type in hindi in your text box; set font of text box to `"Kruti Dev 040, 9.749999pt"`